# Accessing the full DataRow from the DataSource in a ListView ItemDataBound event handler

Tags: asp.net, listview, datasource

Is it at all possible within a ListView ItemDataBound event handler to gain access to the full DataRow for that event?  I need to do a lot of processing for the entire row on binding, but using data item values in the datarow that I am not actually using in the display itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

`DataRowView dr = (DataRowView)DataBinder.GetDataItem(e.Item);`

using 
dr.Item.ItemArray you can access the entire row.

Comment: They must have changed this since whatever version of .NET you're using.  There does not appear to be an .Item.ItemArray anymore.  You can get at the columns by dr.Row["ColumnName"] though.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try to use the `ListViewDataItem` property to access the properties of the underlying data object to which the object is bound. The ListViewDataItem property is only available during and after the ItemDataBound events of the control and usually corresponds to a record in your data source object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listviewdataitem.aspx

Below is an example.

```
protected void listProducts_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
  {
    ListViewDataItem dataItem = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;
    string prodtype = (string)DataBinder.Eval(dataItem, "ProductType");
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Close, but as far as I can tell that only gets me access to the one data item - the item that is being bound at that specific moment, and not the entire data row that is being bound in that iteration of the ListView ItemTemplate.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean only one field for a given row or do you need to reference data from another row?

Comment: I think you meant Eval(dataItem.DataItem, "ProductType");

Then this works